# Write Multiline Arithmetic in Ruby

Tags: ruby

How to write multiline arithmetic properly in Ruby? Previously, i have tried something like `y`, then i realized there is something wrong with that code. I need to write multiline arithmetic due to my very long equation.

```
a = 5
b = 5

x = (a + b) / 2

puts x # 5, as expected

y = (
      a
      + b
    ) /
    2

puts y # 2, what happened?
```

Comment: no exception, the // comment mark was wrong, sorry, it just only for clarifying the output of the program. Edited. Thanks for correction.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The Ruby parser will assume a statement has ended if it looks like it has ended at an end of the line.

What you can to do prevent that is to leave the arithmetic operator just before a new line, like this:

```
a = 1
b = 2
c = a + 
    b
```

And you'll get the result you expect.

Comment: Alternatively you can also prevent parsing of end of statement with a `\\` (backslash character) followed with newline.

Comment: **a statement has ended ... if it looks like it has ended at an end of the line** is almost a tautology. It is not explaining anything.

Comment: It may be a tautology, but it's one that immediately made sense to me, and explained the concept clearly.

Answer (score 4):

```
(
  expr1
  expr2
 )
```

is actually, in Ruby, the same as

```
(expr1; expr2)
```

which just executes the first expression (for side effects) and returns the second one (also after evaluating it)

Comment: So it is impossible to write multiline arithmetics?

Comment: @fidz.id It is possible. Maurício Linhares described how in his answer, which is 100% correct.

Comment: Upvoted as it doesn't deserve somebody's downvote. Ven is correct the OP's code is interpreted as `(a; +b) / 2 == (5; 5) / 2 == 5 / 2 == 2` - integer division.

Comment: The current accepted answer also doesn't provide a solution to force precedence

Answer (score 3):

Try thinking about the "expectations" of the interpreter, and remember that in ruby EVERYTHING is an expression (which means that everything evaluates to some value, even constructs that in other languages are considered "special", like if-then-elses, loops, etcettera).

So:

```
y = (     #1
  a       #2
  + b     #3
) /       #4
2         #5
```

At line 1 we start the declaration of a variable, and the line ends with an open (pending) parenthesis. The interpreter expects the rest of the definition, so it proceeds to the next line looking for a VALUE to assign to the var `y`.

At line 2, the interpreter finds the variable `a`, but no enclosing parenthesis. It evaluates `a`, which has value `5`, and since the line 2 is a perfectly-valid expression, the interpreter understands that this expression is finished (since in Ruby a newline OFTEN means end-of-expression indicator). 
So up to now it has produced a value `5`, but the only expectation it still has is that it must match the enclosing parenthesis.

If after that the interpreter had found the enclosing parenthesis, it would have assigned the value of `a (i.e. 5)` to the parenthesis expression (because everything must have a value, and the last value produced will be used).

When the interpreter reaches line 3, it finds another perfectly-valid ruby expression, `+ b`. Since `+ 5` (`5` being the value of variable `b`) is a VALID integer declaration in ruby, the interpreter sees it as standalone, not at all related to the previous `5` evaluated for the variable `a` (remember, it had no other expectation, except the one for the parenthesis). 
In short, it throws away the value obtained for `a`, and uses only the value obtained with `+ b`. In the next line it finds the enclosing parenthesis, and so the parenthesis-expression gets assigned the last produced value, which is a `5` produced by the expression `+ b`.

Since on line 4 the interpreter finds a `/`, it (correctly) understands it as the division method of an integer, since it has produced an integer up to now (the int `5`)! This creates the expectation for possible arguments of the method, which it finds on line 5. The resulting evaluated expression is `y = 5 / 2`, which equals `2` in integer division. So, basicaly, here is what the interpreter did:

```
y = (    # Ok, i'm waiting for the rest of the parenthesis expression
    a    # cool, a has value 5, if the parenthesis ends here, this is the value of the expr.
    + b  # Oh, but now I found + b, which has value + 5, which evaluates to 5. So now this is the last value I have evaluated.
  ) /    # Ok, the parenthesis have been closed, and the last value I had was a 5. Uow, wait, there is a slash / there! I should now wait for another argument for the / method of the 5 I have!
  2      # Found, let's make y = 5 / 2 = 2!
```

The problem here is that on line #2, you should have left an expectation for the interpreter (exactly as you left on line 4 with the `/` method), which you did not!

The answer of @Maurício Linhares suggests exactly this:

```
y = (
  a +
  b
) /
2
```

By moving the `+` method to the end of the line 2, you tell the interpreter that your expression is still not complete! So it keeps the expectation and proceeds to line #3 to find the right operand of the expression (or, more precisely in Ruby, an argument for the `+` method :D).

The same works with string concatenation:

```
# WRONG, SINCE + "somestring" is not a valid stand-alone expression in ruby    
str = "I like to"
    + " move it!"
# NoMethodError: undefined method `+@' for " move it!":String

# CORRECT, by leaving the + sign as last statement of the first line, you 
# keep the 'expectation' of the interpreter for the next 
# argument of the + method of the string object "I like to"
str = "I like to" +
    " move it!" 
# => "I like to move it!"
```

The difference is that in your code there were no error thrown, since + b is actually a valid expression.

I hope my answer was useful on giving you some intuition on WHY it was not working as expected, sorry if I'm not concise :)